# Drag and drop widget outside source application widgets

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a Qt Desktop aplication which has several top-level widgets. Subwidgets of top-level widgets can be moved between top-level widgets by using drag-and-drop mechanism.

The problem i have now is to drop a sub-widget outside any of existing top-level widgets and create a new top-level widget to contain this one. Lets call this separation.

Can this be done using drag-and-drop? I could not find a way where my dropEvent goes? 
Can i want to handle the drop event in my application even if the drop place is not allowed? Maybe a mouse release or something?

I cannot change everything now but also a question for the future. Is docking/undocking a better way to do this?

Regards
Mihai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this. When drag moves outside of the application widgets QDrag object emits a targetChanged signal with 0 parameter.

So i inherited from QDrag and then emit a custom signal in destructor if the target() is null.

The only problem is that the cursor looks like interdiction of drop and this i could not fix because QDrag can only set cursor pixmap for valid actions like Move or Copy or Link

Update:

Here is the inherited class.

```
class TabDrag: public QDrag
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TabDrag(QWidget *dragSource);
    ~TabDrag();

signals:
    void tearOff(); /// emit tearOff signal if the QDrag object is destroyed and target was null
};

TabDrag::TabDrag(QWidget *dragSource):QDrag(dragSource)
{
}

TabDrag::~TabDrag()
{
    // check if we need to detach this tab
    if(!target())
    {
        emit tearOff();
    }
}
```

The tearOff signal should be connected to whatever you want to happen. In my case i pull out the widget from the tab and change parent to a new window.

Example of usage

```
void MyTabBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
..................
    TabDrag * drag = new TabDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setPixmap(*m_tabPixmap.data());
    drag->setHotSpot(QPoint(m_dragStartPos.x() - tabAtRect.x(), m_dragStartPos.y() - tabAtRect.y()));
    drag->exec();

    connect(drag, SIGNAL(tearOff()), this, SLOT(onTearOff()));
}
```

Comment: Researching the same question for Qt5 and find this clever answer. But to what do you connect the targetChanged signal? What widget receives this notice? Do you connect it back to the custom Drag object itself? Or to the source widget that created the Drag and called its exec? Also, in the slot for targetChanged, could you not at that time call dragobj.setDragCursor(custom cursor pixmap) ? Thanks.  Ooooh, also! The Qt5 doc for Drag::exec() says "On Windows, the Qt event loop is blocked during the operation." So no signals?

Comment: First using exec is never a good idea because you create a sub-event loop which might produce event inversion which will probably lead you to a crash. Qt is not so good with subevent loops. Do not use them. I speak from crashes i experienced because of some modal popup

Comment: Yeah you are right. I also use exec(). I did not remember that. Hmm...then i should research my own advice :). Probably if the event loop is blocked then you cannot have window updates while dragging.

Comment: Let's hope Qt5 brings better options but i do not have this luxury

Comment: If you find anything for Qt5 let me know please. I am also interested.

Comment: I did more research on this but of course I am working in Python/PyQt5, not C++. I wrote up what I found in my blog here: http://thispageintentionally.blogspot.com/2014/01/ts-drag-and-drop-architecture-for.html -- bottom line: immediately after the drag exec call completes, call QCursor::pos() to get the cursor position. This will surely be the drop point, or very close to it. With that it is easy to find out if the cursor was inside or outside your window rectangle.

Comment: How about the icon of the drag? Did you find a way to change this when you drop outside? I did not manage to do that.I see you tried with the Mime data and so on.

Comment: I have not tried. I suppose you tried QDrag::setDragCursor()? What happened?

Comment: The `tearOff()` is also emitted when the drag is cancelled. So, that does not work.

Comment: Also, it seems unnecessary to reimplement `QDrag` since `QObject`s already come with a `destroyed()` signal that can be used directly.